# phpmyadmin on raspbian busetr cannot log in

Tags: phpmyadmin, raspbian-buster

Latest Raspbian Buster fresh install on Pi 3B
Apache2 installed and working
PHP 7.3 installed and Working
MariaDB 10.3.22 installed and working
PHPMyAdmin installed and appears to work
database mysql table user shows 2 users for localhost, root with no password and phpmyadmin with a hashed password.
database phpmyadmin table pma__users has no records

When I start PHPMyAdmin and get the log in screen what username/password do I use?

Do I manually need to add a user? If yes, how?

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found a solution on your own, but to answer the question for future searchers:

When using phpMyAdmin, you're just using your normal MySQL credentials. Most distribution package managers will prompt you to create a password for the MySQL root user when installing the MySQL package. The MySQL root user is different from the system root user, despite having the name in common. If you install from source, the default is typically the username root with a blank password.

You might not wish to operate from day-to-day as the root user, in which case you can log in as root and then create a new user for your normal operations.

It seems you've used the package manager to also install phpMyAdmin, because it's gone ahead and created the control user automatically. The phpMyAdmin control user is an extra account that has special permissions to give you access to some advanced features (like bookmarked queries, a query history, etc). You can see more about creating the controluser in the documentation at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration or learn more about the advanced features at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables

Answer (score 0):

I used the mysql CLI to create a user and used that to login to phpmyadmin.